# putStringSet() SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I have three inputs that the user puts and I need to save this data in his phone, I first thought about saving as an array, so I could have an Id for when I wanted it back, but I searched and everybody uses this [PutStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), I did some research but didn`t find anyone that could help me on how to use that with SharedPreferences.
Thanks...

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials online for `SharedPreferences` --give it a google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the Strings in an array, all you need is this:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(myKey, mySet).apply();
```

Then to retrieve it:

```
Set<String> mySet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(myKey, null);
for(String myString : mySet) {
    //do something with myString
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jeremy Figgins, thanks for your reply, sorry that I didn`t put this in my original question, but by using your code, how would I loop through each element (getting from the SharedPreferences) so I could display it back for the user (everything that he has saved)